# Convergence to a delta distribution

Tags: probability, probability-theory, limits, probability-distributions

Is it Okay to say that when I have a probability density $P(x;\mu,\sigma)$, with $\mu$ the first moment of the probability density and $\sigma$ the square root of the second central moment of the probability density that the following relation holds:

$\lim\limits_{\sigma\rightarrow0}P(x;\mu,\sigma) = \delta(x-\mu)$, where $\delta(x-\mu)$ is my delta-distribution centered around $\mu$?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Indeed, $P[A;\mu,\sigma]\to1$ if $\mu$ is in $A$ and $P[A;\mu,\sigma]\to0$ if $\mu$ is not in $A$. If this is how you define $\delta$, the limit holds.